# Splitting the screen into half(horizontally) while using a border for TextViews (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout which divides the screen into two horizontally and it works correctly. But when I try to put a border (as a background image from my custom drawable folder) the second TextView does not start at the half of the page. It comes next to the first view. How can I fix?

Here is that part of my xml.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border_tasks"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bekleyen                 \n Görevler \n 10"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Biten                     \n Görevler \n 90"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the full xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/activitychart"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/border_name"
       android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text ="Adı Soyadı"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Anadolu Sigorta - Eksper"
        />
   </LinearLayout>
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:background="@drawable/border_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:scaleX="1.02"
        android:scaleY="1.02"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_tasks"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bekleyen                 \n Görevler \n 10"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Biten                     \n Görevler \n 90"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is border tasks (values are just random, you can change them.)
The reason I use two different textviews is that I will add an additional border for each text view after adding a wider border which encapsulates both of them

border_tasks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <size android:width="@dimen/_160sdp" android:height="@dimen/_60sdp" ></size>
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="@dimen/_160sdp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
</shape>
```

Here @dimen/_160sdp refers to 160 dp and so on. I played with the values but I could not make it work.

Comment: To really see the space occupied by the textviews change the background color. I think you will see the are 50/50. If it is the case, check the text alignment of the TextViews.

Comment: They are not 50 50.

Comment: Are you changing any layout in code?

Comment: No code does not change any layout. This xml works as expected when I dont put a border

Comment: Further trials showed me that all of the textviews fill the half ot the screen when I add a border. So if I add 5 textviews each will hold 1/10 of the screen

Comment: can you add the border xml

Comment: Sorry, I thought I added it when I asked the question. I added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the border_task.xml.
I changed it by removing the size tag and changing the padding to 10dp from all directions.

This generates a rounded border containing both textviews. And the text views occupy 50/50 of the space.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
    </shape>
```

Hint: to separate the border of the LinearLayout from the border of the screen add a margin of 5dp to the LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks, while pasting the xml file to you, I also realized that commenting out the paddings kinda solve the issue. But this is more accurate, I am accepting it as an answer